# A question related to the convergence of characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Assuming the following assumptions:

1. $\underset{n \to \infty}{\limsup}  \sum_{j=1}^n  | 1-  \varphi_{jn}(u)|< \infty$;
2. $s_n = \sup_{1\leq j \leq n}|1-  \varphi_{jn}(u)| \to 0$, as $n \to \infty$

I am trying to show a convergence involving characteristic functions $\varphi_{jn}$ :
$$\sum_{j=1}^n  | \varphi_{jn}(u) - \exp\{ \varphi_{jn}(u) -1 \} | \to 0 \quad(n \to \infty) $$

My attempt begins using the following: first note that the ch. f. of some random vector $X$ is such that  $\varphi(u)= E[\cos(u'X)] + i E[\sin(u'X)]$, i.e., the $Re(\varphi(u))\leq 1$. So, $Re(\varphi(u)-1) \leq 0$. Thus, we are able to use this [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718800/remainder-term-in-taylor-series-for-the-complex-exponential-map) and conclude that:
$$|P_1(z)- e^z|= |1+ z - e^z |\leq |z|^2, \quad z = \varphi_{jn}(u) -1 $$
i.e.
\begin{equation}\label{taylor}\tag{T}
|\varphi_{jn}(u) - \exp\{\varphi_{jn}(u) -1 \} |= |1+ (\varphi_{jn} -1 ) - \exp\{\varphi_{jn} -1 \} |\leq |\varphi_{jn}(u) -1|^2
\end{equation}
Aggregating:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n  | \varphi_{jn}(u) - \exp\{ \varphi_{jn}(u) -1 \} |\leq \sum_{j=1}^n |\varphi_{jn}(u) -1||\varphi_{jn}(u) -1|\leq s_n  \sum_{j=1}^n |\varphi_{jn}(u) -1|$$
Note that if $x_n\geq 0$ and $\limsup x_n =0$, then $\lim x_n =0$. So
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n  | \varphi_{jn}(u) - \exp\{ \varphi_{jn}(u) -1 \} |\leq \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n  \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n |\varphi_{jn}(u) -1|\overset{\hbox{ by 1 and 2}}{=}0$$

I am very unsure about my attempt and would like to know if there are any errors in my demo, mainly because, in fact, the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718800/remainder-term-in-taylor-series-for-the-complex-exponential-map) mentioned above is true for $Re(z)<1$. Is this true for the case $Re(z)=0$ ?

I greatly appreciate your feedback.