# Taylor's formula for $e^{ix}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $i$ be the complex number $i^2 = -1$.
I want to prove that
$$
\Biggl| e^{i x} - \sum_{j = 0}^N \frac{(i x)^j}{j!} \Biggr|\leq \frac{ | x |^{N+1} }{(N+1)!}
$$
hold for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
This should follow from some form of Taylor's theorem.

I don't think I can apply the real Taylor's theorem, because it's a complex function, but
I also can not apply complex Taylor theorem because I am only considering $x \in \mathbb{R}$, instead of an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. How can I deduce this? Thank you!

Comment: Use induction, integrating the inequality at each step to go to the next step. Can you prove this for $N=0$?

Comment: You can write $e^{ix} = cos(x) + isin(x)$, and split the series to real (even $j$'s) and complex (odd $j$'s), and use the triangular inequality. After that you can apply the real Taylor's theorem for each of the terms.

Comment: @geetha290krm I am not seeing how to prove it for $N=0$... How do you deal with the case $|x| \geq 1$?

Comment: I am not posting an answer because this question has been answered before on MSE.

Comment: The answer can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718800/remainder-term-in-taylor-series-for-the-complex-exponential-map

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor formula with  the integral form tells you that the remainder is $R_n(x)=\int _0^x f^{[N+1]} (t)(x-t)^N {dt \over N!}$.  In your case, $\vert f^{[N+1]}(t) \vert =1$ your result follows.